# Gnuplot Histogram w/ Error Bars

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, histogram

I'm trying to make a bar chart /histogram with Gnuplot but I cant seem to get the error bars to come out.

This is my code:

```
set style data errorbars 
set style histogram errorbars gap 2 lw 1
set style data histograms
plot "ctcf.dat" using 2:3:3:xtic(1)
```

and data:

```
 #Label  Mean        Error
 168-B  24778.23544 33467.8754
 168-S  34067.82997 35542.62473
 168-B  22519.51553 30835.37332
 168-S  112976.1825 143760.3467
```

But they come out wrong:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When plotting histograms with errorbars you need to give only two columns in the `using` statement. The first column gives the box height, the second one is `±<error>`:

```
set style histogram errorbars gap 1 lw 1
set style data histograms
plot "ctcf.dat" using 2:3:xtic(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to centre the boxes over the x labels?

Comment: Yes, use `gap 1`. If you want to change the boxwidth, use e.g. `set boxwidth 0.8 relative` to get a bit smaller boxes.

Comment: Thanks! one more q: How can I colour specific boxes?

Comment: Depends on the selection criterium for the color. If it should be based on the label, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25534986/2604213 or be more specific.