# Putting errobar in gnuplot histogram boxplot

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I have the following data,

```
          AAA      BBB      CCC      DDD
300K    7054.67  7339.43  7945.14  0 
500K    9536.64  9618.97  5816.01  909.298
700K    8746.1   8938.58  7350.93  3720.61
```

and I used this gnuplot script to get a plot.

```
reset
set encoding utf8
set term postscript eps enhanced color "Times-Roman, 20"
set output 'test.eps'
set style data histogram
set boxwidth 1
set yrange [0:12000]
set style fill solid border -1
data1 = "file"
plot for [COL=2:5] data1 u COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader
```

But how can I draw errorbars for the columns? I prepared the additional columns as

```
water     AAA     AAAdy        BBB      BBBdy        CCC       CCCdy       DDD      DDDdy
300K    7054.67    350       7339.43     300       7945.14      300         0          0
500K    9536.64    300       9618.97     300       5816.01      300      909.298     300
700K    8746.1     300       8638.58     300       7350.93      300      3720.61     300
```

I'm not sure how can I use those additional columns for the y-dir errorbars (3rd, 5th, 7th, and 9th).

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25551280/2604213